# How to add multiple items to labels using reportlab and pylabels

Tags: python, reportlab

My goal is to eventually create printable labels (for sticking on physical boxes) from a data frame.  Right now, I'd like to know what I can do to add more than one unique item to a label.  So far, I have

```
import labels
import reportlab
from reportlab.graphics import shapes

specs = labels.Specification(210, 297, 2, 2, 100, 125, corner_radius=2)

def draw_label(label, width, height, obj):
    label.add(shapes.String(100, 50, str(obj), fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=40))
    label.add(shapes.String(100, 100, str(obj), fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=40))

sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, draw_label, border=True)

for i in range(10):
    sheet.add_label("Hello" + "\r\n" + "hi", count=2)
    sheet.add_label("World")
```

which outputs 10 pages of labels that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftsl3.png).
My question: How can I get more than one unique item on each label?  The `sheet.add_label()` doesn't seem to allow me to add more than one object into a label.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you figure how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define list of values and send them as obj parameter:

```
def draw_label(label, width, height, obj):
     label.add(shapes.String(2, 2, str(obj[0]), fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=12))
     label.add(shapes.String(2, 20, str(obj[1]), fontName="Helvetica", fontSize=12))

sheet.add_label(['Name','Surname'])
```